# Is it possible to use Accounts from Apple Calender in Outlook 2016?

Tags: mac, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office

since Outlook is not able to sync with my Zarafa-Server I want to use the Calendar in Apples Calendar-App (Its not in the iCloud, its synced with my Server).
Is there any possitbility to use the calendar from Outlook 2k16?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following steps to connect Zarafa server calendar to Mac Calendar program:

1. Open Calendar program on Mac.
2. Click Calnedar > Preferences.
3. Select Account tab, click + button to add new calendar.
4. Choose Other CalDAV Account, click Continue.
5. Select Account Type to Manual. Fill in the User Name and Password.
6. In Server Address, use the URL below for Zarafa server: https://doc.zarafa.com/6.40/User_Manual/en-US/html/_configure_canlendar_clients.html
7. Click Sign In to setup it.